# Count points on x-axis

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, number-theory, trigonometry

Given S and C . There are S sine functions and C cosine functions as following:

$F(i,x)$ = $sin(2^i x)$,  $0 ≤ x ≤ 2π$, for $i = 0, 1, ..., S−1$

$G(j,x)$ = $cos(2^j x)$,  $0 ≤ x ≤ 2π$, for $j = 0, 1, ..., C−1$

We need to find points on x-axis such that at least $K$ functions intersect on those points.

**Example** : Let take the case of $S = 3, C = 2$ and $K=1$ then here answer is $9$

**Explanation** : We have $3$ sin waves : $sin(x)$ , $sin(2x)$ and $sin(4x)$ . Also we have $2$ cos waves : $cos(x)$, $cos(2x)$.

There are $9$ points on the x-axis such that at least $1$ function through the points. That is, $x = 0, π/4, π/2, 3π/4, π, 5π/4, 3π/2, 7π/4, 2π$

**Now given S, C and K can we generalise any formula for finding count of these points ?**

Comment: It should be easy to enumerate, for each integer multiple of $\pi/2^{\max\{S,C\}}$, the exact number of functions $F$ and $G$ that have a zero there. It seems that this would basically solve your problem.

Comment: @GregMartin How to enumerate it ? Please help. How to find integral multiples

Comment: @GregMartin Writing a program in computer , won't there be precision issues ?

Comment: @GregMartin So I was thinking if their can be some formula or approach in which use of pi and other such computations can be avoided

Comment: $\sin x=0$ if and only if $x=k\pi$ for some $k\in\mathbb Z$. So $\sin(2^ix)=0$ if and only if $2^ix=k\pi$ which means $x=k2^{-i}\pi$. Likewise $\cos x=0$ holds for $x=(k+\frac12)\pi$ so $\cos(2^jx)=0$ holds for $x=(2k+1)2^{-j-1}\pi$. So let's define $t:=2^{-\max(S,C)}\pi$ Then all the zeros described above will be at positions which are an integral multiple of $t$. (I intended to expand this to an answer, but don't have the time for it, hence I'll leave it as this comment.)

Comment: [Contest question](http://www.codechef.com/MARCH15/problems/SIGNWAVE), locked until contest is over.